# Changing where dropdown appears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown I'm working with defined as follows:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">company</button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">apple</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">microsoft</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">adobe</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">other</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

The dropdown works great, the only problems is that when it's clicked, the list of items to choose from appears positioned beneath the dropdown (by default).  What I would like to do is change this positioning so that the list appears centered *on top* of the dropdown (aka the dropdown button is covered)

Not really sure what to tinker with to get this one, I searched on S/O but was unable to find a related post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css property

```
.dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with top and left properties:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    top: -4px;
    left: -2px;
}
```